# Powershell DataGridViewButtonColumn : Button Text Customize

Tags: powershell

[enter image description here][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7AhL.png Hi Im using a Gridview Output in a Custom Form Im stuck at the above Image Label: UninstallFunction: Uninstall My Code: #Start-Process Powershell -verb runas # Load Windows Forms assembly [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") [void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles() # Create a GUI $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(920,500) $form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Fixed3D $form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen $dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView $dataGridView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(900,400) $button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button $button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,420) $button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25) $button.text = "Uninstall" $form.Controls.Add($button) $form.Controls.Add($dataGridView) # Select appropriate columns $dataGridView.Columns.Insert(0, (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonColumn)) $dataGridView.ColumnCount = 9 $dataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true $dataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "Uninstall" $dataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "Description" $dataGridView.Columns[2].Name = "IdentifyingNumber" $dataGridView.Columns[3].Name = "Name" $dataGridView.Columns[4].Name = "Vendor" $dataGridView.Columns[5].Name = "Version" $dataGridView.Columns[6].Name = "Caption" $dataGridView.Columns[7].Name = "InstallLocation" $dataGridView.Columns.Insert(8, (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonCell)) $dataGridView.Columns[0].width = 50 $dataGridView.Columns[1].width = 200 # Get a list of items <#Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | foreach { $dataGridView.Rows.Add($*.Check,$*.Description,$*.IdentifyingNumber,$*.Name,$*.Vendor,$*.Version,$*.Caption,$*.InstallLocation) | out-null }#> # Refresh function gridClick(){ $dataGridView.Text = 'Delete selected rows' $rowIndex = $dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index $columnIndex0 = $dataGridView.ColumnIndex+1 $columnIndex1 = $dataGridView.ColumnIndex+2 $columnIndex2 = $dataGridView.ColumnIndex+3 $columnIndex3 = $dataGridView.ColumnIndex+4 $columnIndex5 = $dataGridView.ColumnIndex+5 #Write-Host $rowIndex #Write-Host $columnIndex0 #Write-Host $dataGridView.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[0].value Write-Host $dataGridView.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[$columnIndex0].value Write-Host $dataGridView.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[$columnIndex1].value Write-Host $dataGridView.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[$columnIndex5].value #$IdentifyNumber = $dataGridView.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[$ClassKey].value #$Name = $dataGridView.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[$columnIndex0].value #$classKey = 'IdentifyingNumber=$IdentifyingNumber.value,Name=$Name.value,Version=$Version.value' #Write-Host $classKey #([wmi]”\$server\root\cimv2:Win32_Product.$classKey”).uninstall() } $Uninstall = $dataGridView.Add_CellMouseClick({gridClick}) # Show the form [void]$form.ShowDialog()

### I want to Add Label to the Command Box. (Please Refer to the Screen Shot attached) This a Custom Form with a GridView Output where for Each Column I need to add a Button. I need to put a Label in the button.

Comment: Please format your question properly and ask clearly what you need

Comment: Please refer to the Image. That should help you to understand.

Comment: I feel I have given all required info. Even the Screen is Clear. I want to Add Label to the CommandBox. I don't know how to make it more simple. Can anyone help me in this ?

Comment: Thanks to All.. I have solved this...

Comment: I've rollback your replacement of the question by a solution. Please clarify your question to make it on topic, then flag it for re-opening, then post your solution as an answer of its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try changing the value ,like this in your grid click function:

```
 $dataGridView.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[0].Value = "test value"
```